# Can blender take a mesh and protect areas of detail before applying a decimator?

Tags: mesh

Agisoft Photoscan created a 12million face mesh but a lot of that I dont need on pipes and things, but I do need it on some fine detail. decimate if applying 10% of the faces wrecks everything. We can enter a face count but its tricky knowing what will retain detail yet lessen faces, to be honest any lessening is not good on the fine areas that I am just about seeing anyway !  I need to protect the detail areas and reduce the face count of pipes and tyre walls except for raised data on them and other smooth surfaces and such things.
could I import into blender and then do that and what would happen to the mapped image texture ?

Otherwise I am rotating a mesh sluggishly before importing into rhino for surface work where again it will be very slow or crash.

Steve1

Comment: Decimate will make everything possible to conserve details. Triming the faces to where they are needed for topology.

Comment: Select vertices that needs to be decimated (where you don't need the fine detail) and add them to a vertex group. Then in Decimate modifier, choose this vertex group.

Comment: Hi, Sounds promising if I can find out how in Blenders interface I do that. Need to see a tutorial now, any links welcome. Yvain are you saying decimate preserves detail by being clver and knowing where it is itself, or do I have to show it ? Jan method sees human brain decide where the detail is.  Is the process in the user manual I wonder or something that one gets to know about with use. Steve1